# Unable to call multiple view from the same controller in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have created two views in CodeIgniter and I have created controller named `HelloWorld.php`
It contains two views.. but my problem is that the second view never gets called.

```
http://localhost/CodeIgniter/HelloWorld/Hello
```

Works fine for me, but second view

```
http://localhost/CodeIgniter/HelloWorld/Buzz
```

Doesn't call the second view

Here is my code

```
<?php

class HelloWorld extends CI_Controller
{
    var $name;
    var $color;

    function __construct()
    {
        parent:: __construct();

        $this->name= 'Suzzu';
        $this->color = 'aqua';
    }

    public function Hello()
    {
        $this->load->view("hello");
    }

    public function Buzz()
    {
        $data['name'] = $this->name;
        $data['color'] = $this->color;

        $this->load->view("welcome",$data);
    }
}
```

what's the problem ??

Comment: So what happens when you go to http://localhost/CodeIgniter/HelloWorld/Buzz? What is the problem?

Comment: And you have a file named `welcome.php` in your `views` directory? Can you post the contents of the file?

Comment: When I go to localhost/CodeIgniter/HelloWorld/Buzz  .. it will display the content of first view that is hello.php

Comment: this is welcome.php <body bgcolor="<?=$color?>">

<h2> Hello, <?=$name ?> We Welcome you in CodeIgniter !! </h2> 
</body>
</html>

Answer (score 0):

Your code works as expected for me provided that:

- there is a view file "views/welcome.php"
- there is a view file "views/hello.php"

Can you verify that HelloWorld::Buzz() is being called?

```
public function Buzz()
{
    die('yes, it works');
}
```

If this function doesn't execute when you go to /localhost/CodeIgniter/HelloWorld/Buzz, can you provide the following:

- $config['base_url'] (config/config.php)
- $config['index_page']
- config/routes.php contents

Comment: $config['index_page'] = 'index.php'

Comment: $route['default_controller'] = "helloworld";

Comment: So if you navigate to /localhost/CodeIgniter/HelloWorld/Buzz with the 'die()' statement as the first line of the function, what happens?

Comment: As usual function doesn't call at all !!

Comment: What about your 404 page?  Are you overriding it in your $route['404_override'] setting by any chance?  Also, can you verify that going to http://localhost/CodeIgniter/HelloWorld/Hello is actually hitting the HelloWorld::Hello() function?

Comment: yes.. localhost/CodeIgniter/HelloWorld/Hello is actually hitting HelloWorld::Hello()  and i have not override error page

Comment: It will show sevrity error :  color variable is not defined name is not defined

Comment: I would strip everything out of the class except for the two functions, the view loads inside them and go from there.

Answer (score 0):

change `$config['base_url']="localhost/codeigniter/contollername"`